# How can I connect the pipes?

Tags: broken-age

I'm playing Vella's first scene in act 2. I've recovered the helmet, but I can't find a way to connect the pipes.

I can't cut the hose from the bottom, and if I climb it, it won't let me cut from the top either. I can't find anything else around that I can use, nor can I use any other items.

I feel like I've tried every item/interactable combination - what am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have Maintenance Panel 36 (the middle one) "open" (sticking out) before you can cut the hose from the top.

By cutting the bottom of the hose, you should have gotten a short hose segment.

To open maintenance panels, you have to use the small hose to connect two pipes from the left set.

I believe the correct setting is connecting the top and bottom hoses from the left set.

Comment: Where are the maintenance panels?

Comment: @fredley They're hexagons that stick out from the walls.  There are 3 total that can be opened, but you need the middle one to be open before you can cut the hose from the top end.

Comment: Can you add a picture? I can't find any intractable hexagons...

Comment: @fredley I'm at work at the moment, so no.  btw, when I saw "open" I'm using the ship's computer's wording as they really just stick out from the wall.  You "open" them by using the short piece of hose you got from cutting the bottom of the hose and connecting two of the left set of pipes together with it.